# Create CDF from a custom function

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

I have a complex function as follows (sorry for ugly script due to many parameters in the code!) which gives CDF of some data. I wonder whether there's any way to write it in CDF form in Mathematica, so I can use the statistical tools in Mathematica to apply it to datasets.

Here, `qq`, `kk` are the data variables and `λ0, ρ0, δ0, Q, K, ell` are the model parameters.

```
F[qq_, kk_, λ0_, ρ0_, δ0_, Q_, K_, ell_] := 
  Module[{t, Eg, Fs, F, Vs, pvals, p, Es, E0, V0, F0, g0, g1, E2, V2, 
    F2, Qvals, erf, EV0, λ, ρ, δ, μell, fρe, λmax},
   t = (Q 15)/60; 
   μell = (ell K)/1000;
   Eg = μell/λ;
   fρe[λ_, ρ_, δ_] := (1.418 λ^2 + 0.734 δ λ - 4.785 λ + 4.712) ρ;
   ρ = ρ0; λ = λ0; δ = δ0; λmax = 0.0003526093088857546 (4785. - 734. δ);
   E0 = 1/(fρe[Min[λ, λmax], ρ0, δ0] + 1);
   V0 = (2 Eg δ^2 ρ^2)/((ρ + 1)^3 t);
   F0[q_] := Evaluate[CDF[NormalDistribution[E0, Sqrt[V0]], q]];
   E2[k_, pm_] := (k (2 λ) pm)/(λ + (δ^2 + 2 ρ + 1) ρ) + (ρ δ^2 + λ + ρ)/(λ + (δ^2 + 2 ρ + 1) ρ); 
   V2[k_, pm_] := 1/(t (λ + (δ^2 + 2 ρ + 1) ρ)^3)*
      2 Eg (δ^2 + 1) ρ (((ρ + 1) δ^4 + 2 (2 ρ^2 + ρ + 1) δ^2 + (ρ + 1)*
      (2 ρ + 1)^2) k^2 pm^2 λ^2 + 2 k pm ρ ((δ^2 - 2 ρ + 1)*(-ρ) δ^2 + 2 λ ρ^2 +
      λ + (δ^2 + 3) λ ρ) λ + ρ^2 (λ^2 + (2 δ^2 + λ) ρ λ + 2 (δ^2 + 1) δ^2 ρ^2)); 
   F2[q_, k_, pm_] := Evaluate[CDF[NormalDistribution[E2[k - 1/2, pm], Sqrt[V2[k - 1/2, pm]]], q]];
   Es[p_, k_, 
     pm_] := ((δ^2 + 1) p + (2 k pm + 1) (ρ + 1) λ)/((δ^2 + 2 ρ + 1) p + λ + ρ (ρ δ^2 + λ + ρ)); 
   Vs[p_, k_, pm_] := (Eg (4 (ρ + 1) k^2 ((δ^2 + 1)^2 ((2 ρ + 1) δ^2 + 1) ρ^4 + 
     (δ^2 + 1) ((2 ρ^3 + 3 ρ^2 + ρ + 1) δ^4 + (6 ρ^3 + 4 ρ^2 + 4 ρ + 2) δ^2 +
     8 ρ^3 + 13 ρ^2 + 3 ρ + 1) p ρ + (δ^2 - 1) (δ^2 + 2 ρ + 1)^2 p^3 +
     ((2 ρ^2 + 2 ρ + 1) δ^6 + (4 ρ^3 + 6 ρ^2 + 4 ρ + 3) δ^4 + 
     (8 ρ^3 + 6 ρ^2 + 6 ρ + 3) δ^2 - 4 ρ^3 + 2 ρ^2 + 4 ρ + 1) p^2) pm^2 λ^2 + 
     4 (ρ + 1) k pm ρ (-2 (δ^6 - (λ + 2 ρ - 2) δ^4 + (1 - 2 (λ + 1) ρ) δ^2 + λ +
     2 λ ρ) p^3 + (((ρ - 1) δ^4 + (2 ρ - 3) δ^2 + 9 ρ - 2) ρ (δ^2 + 1)^2 + 
     (ρ δ^6 + (4 ρ + 3) ρ δ^4 + (8 ρ^2 + 5 ρ + 2) δ^2 - 4 ρ^2 + 3 ρ + 2) λ) p^2 +
     (δ^2 + 1) ((δ^2 (ρ - 1) - 1) ρ (δ^2 + 1)^2 + (2 (ρ + 1) ρ δ^4 + 
     (6 ρ^2 + 3 ρ + 1) δ^2 + 8 ρ^2 + 13 ρ + 1) λ) ρ p + (δ^2 + 1)^2 ((2 ρ + 1) δ^2 + 1) λ ρ^3) λ +
     ρ^2 (8 (δ^3 + δ)^2 p^4 + (ρ δ^10 + 9 ρ δ^8 + 34 ρ δ^6 + (8 (ρ + 1) λ + 
     58 ρ) δ^4 + (4 (ρ + 1) λ^2 + 8 (ρ + 1) λ + 45 ρ) δ^2 - 4 (ρ + 1) λ^2 + 13 ρ) p^3 + 
     2 ((δ^2 + 2) ρ^2 (δ^2 + 1)^4 + (ρ + 1) (δ^4 + 2 δ^2 + 9) λ ρ (δ^2 + 1)^2 + 
     2 ((ρ + 1) ρ δ^4 + (2 ρ^2 + 3 ρ + 1) δ^2 - ρ^2 + 1) λ^2) p^2 + 
     (δ^2 + 1) ρ (ρ^2 (δ^2 + 1)^4 + ((2 ρ^2 + 3 ρ + 1) δ^4 + 
     (6 ρ^2 + 8 ρ + 2) δ^2 + 8 ρ^2 + 21 ρ + 13) λ^2 + 2 (ρ + 1) (δ^3 + δ)^2 λ ρ) p + 
     (δ^2 + 1)^2 ((2 ρ + 1) δ^2 + 1) (ρ + 1) λ^2 ρ^2)))/(t (2 (p + ρ) ((δ^2 + 1) ρ^2 + 
     (δ^2 + 2 ρ + 1) p + (ρ + 1) λ)^3)); 
   Fs[q_, p_, k_, pm_] := CDF[NormalDistribution[Es[p, k - 1/2, pm], Sqrt[Vs[p, k - 1/2, pm]]], q]; 
pvals = {0, 1};
   1 - (1 - F0[qq]) Product[1 - Fs[qq, p, kk, pm], {p, pvals}, {pm, {-1, 1}}]];
```

Comment: Have you seen the docs of `ProbabilityDistribution[]`?

Comment: The general form is `dist = ProbabilityDistribution[{"CDF", F[qq, kk, lambda0, rho0, delta0, Q, K, ell]}, {qq, qqmin, qqmax}, {kk, kkmim, kkmax}, Assumptions -> {}]` where the constraints on the parameters are included in the `Assumptions`. However, it is unlikely to have the full functionality of the built-in functions.